# Display download button in Shiny R only when output appears in Main Panel

Tags: r, shiny

I have the below code which allows to accept csv files -> run an R code -> display -> download the output.

But, the download button appears as soon as the app is run.
is there a way to display the output button only when the output file is available?

Below is the code I am using:

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)

#ui.R
# Define UI for random distribution application 
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Text Mining on R"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Select the Input File',
                accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
      tags$hr(),
      fileInput('file2', 'Select the UserTopic file',
                accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv'))

    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput('table'),
      downloadButton('OutputFile', 'Download Output File')
    )
  ))
)
```

**Server.R**

```
#server.R
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({
    file1 = input$file1
    file2 = input$file2
    if (is.null(file1) || is.null(file2)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    data1 = read.csv(file1$datapath,header = TRUE, sep=",",skipNul = TRUE)
    data2 = read.csv(file2$datapath,header = TRUE, sep=",",skipNul = TRUE)
   source("RCode.R", local = TRUE)
    #output$table <- renderDataTable(output2)
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      my_function(file1$datapath,file2$datapath)
    })

    output$OutputFile <- downloadHandler(


      filename = function() {
        paste("OutputFile", "_",Sys.time(),".csv",sep="")
       },

      content = function(file) {


        write.csv(my_function(file1$datapath,file2$datapath), file, sep = ",",
                    row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )
  })

})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On server side you can use:

```
output$download <- renderUI({
  if(!is.null(input$file1) & !is.null(input$file2)) {
    downloadButton('OutputFile', 'Download Output File')
  }
})
```

and on ui side you replace the download button with:

```
uiOutput("download")
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use req().

In the UI:

```
uiOutput("get_the_item")
```

In the server:

```
output$get_the_item <- renderUI({
req(input$file1, input$file2)
downloadButton('download_item', label = 'Download item') })
```

Below the renderUI, add the downloadHandler (complete the code with your arguments for filename and content):

```
output$download_item <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {},
content = function(file) {}
)
```

Comment: The use of `req()` is highly recommended. From https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html: "when you use req to check your preconditions, a failure not only stops the current calculation..., but also any callers on the call stack."

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to hide/show objects in a `shiny` web app is to use the amazing [shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) package from Dean Attali. The package is widley documented and you can find a complete set of working examples on [this page](http://deanattali.com/2015/04/23/shinyjs-r-package/) from Dean's blog.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to solutions above, you can also use `conditionalPanel` as follows :

**ui.R**

```
conditionalPanel("output.fileUploaded",
                   downloadButton('OutputFile', 'Download Output File'))
```

**server.R**

```
getData <- reactive({
if(is.null(input$file1) && is.null(input$file2)) 
  {return(NULL)}
else {return(1)}
})

output$fileUploaded <- reactive({
return(!is.null(getData()))
})
outputOptions(output, 'fileUploaded', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
```

This is just another approach using `conditionalPanel` and `outputOptions`.